# Ford Focus steering wheel vibration and noise from front right wheel4

Tags: ford, tires, focus, steering

I drive a Ford Focus 2004 which has about 104 thousand km on the clock.

There is a constant noise from the front right wheel which goes away when I depress the clutch. Moreover around 60km/h and 120-130km/h there is a vibration in the steering wheel which is sometimes more sometimes less.

The front tires have seen better days and could/should also be replaced but don't show any irregular wear.

What would be the most likely cause? Did anybody have similar experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input shaft bearing on the transmission is suspect. That is turning anytime the engine is running and the clutch petal is not pressed. When you press the clutch the input shaft stops turning.

This answer is assuming, based on your question that the noise is constant anytime the engine is running and the clutch petal is not pressed in. The only time the noise stops is when you push in the clutch, and which gear the transmission is in, makes no difference.

Your steering wheel vibration is likely caused by tires being out of balance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Larry. I'll check tomorrow if the noise is there while the car is stationary. I noticed today on the autobahn that the noise goes away when I depress the clutch.

Comment: Getting two new front tires and getting an alignment done solved my problem. I was having very similar issues.